# How to navigate route with scroll to view

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am navigating to a route like:

`<Link to="/products#product5">Go to projects and focus id</Link>` the target of this link is to go to page and focus to id. but it's not happening. instead I am  landing to `products` page but not focused to `id`. what is the correct way to handle this? it's required only from specified link.

here is my try: `Hello.tsx`

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default ({ name: string }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
    <Link to="/products#product5">Go to projects and focus id</Link>
  </div>
);
```

here is the products page:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import "./products.scss";

const Shoes = React.lazy(() => import("./shoes/shoes.component"));
const Cloths = React.lazy(() => import("./cloths/cloths.component"));

export default class Products extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <header>
          <Link to="/products/shoe">Shoes</Link>
          <Link to="/products/cloths">Cloths</Link>
        </header>
        <h1>Products page</h1>
        <main>
          <Switch>
            <Redirect exact from="/products" to="/products/shoe" />
            <Route path="/products/shoe">
              <Shoes />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/products/cloths">
              <Cloths />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

default shoe page: where the id need to bring to view

```
import React from "react";
import "./shoes.style.scss";

export default class Shoes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="list-shoes">
        <h1>I am from shoe page </h1>
        <span>Product-1</span>
        <span>Product-2</span>
        <span>Product-3</span>
        <span>Product-4</span>
        <span>Product-5</span>
        <span>Product-6</span>
        <span>Product-7</span>
        <span>Product-8</span>
        <span id="product9">Product-9</span>
        <span>Product-10</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://react-tsx-tantum.stackblitz.io/hello)

what is the correct way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try accessing the product directly from the `/products/shoe` route, like `/products/shoe#product9`, you can see that your current approach is working fine. The id `product9` exists in your `Shoes` component, and so it's focused automatically when you enter that route.

However, the issue with the route you're specifying in the question is caused by this redirect here:

```
<Redirect exact from="/products" to="/products/shoe" />
```

As you can see in the example you provided, when you try accessing `/products#product5`, what happpens is that you're automatically redirected to `/products/shoe`. **The hash parameter is not preserved during that redirection**, thus the page doesn't scroll to the id included within the original URL (there's no longer an id to focus).

If you want it to work, **you'll need to manually retrieve the value of the hash and append it to the destination URL before triggering the redirection**. You can do this by using the `render` method of the `Route` component to access the `location` object that React Router provides, and then use it to build the URL to which you want to redirect.

```
<Route exact path="/products" 
  render={({ location }) => <Redirect to={{
    pathname: '/products/shoe',
    hash: location.hash,
  }}
/>
```

With this piece of code, the value of the hash will now be added to the new url, so the id of the item to focus should no longer be lost during redirection. Going back to your example path, `/products#product5` would now redirect to `/products/shoe#product5` instead of `/products/shoe`.

Comment: updated as per your advice. but no result found. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tsx-tantum?file=index.tsx, as well focusing to id is conditional not alwasy required.

Comment: From hello component need to scroll down and need to focus. else it should work by defualts